# Cambiar el contenido de las columnas en DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagrid, usercontrol

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para un calculo de etiquetas dentro del lenguaje C#.

Anexo foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pretendo hacer es insertar un DataGridview pero de acuerdo a la opción que se seleccione: Niño, Dama, Caballero el nombre de las cabeceras de las columnas es diferente para cada uno, así mismo como el numero de columnas que se ocupan. 
Saludos. Espero haberme Explicado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eso lo logras usando DataTable, y el DataGridView sin columnas definidas

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
    dt.Columns.Add("Apellido");
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Clint", "Eastwood" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Leo", "Messi" });
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Correo");
    dt.Columns.Add("Teléfono");
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "cosa@yahoo.com", "342245252" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "humano@gmail.com", "24523466" });
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior creo las columnas en los DataTables pero puedes llenarlo directamente de una consulta con SqlDataReader

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLA", conn);
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

[image: Grid sin columnas]

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas Gracias!!.  Justos a esto me refería, saludos.

Comment: Una ultima pregunta amigo, ¿hay forma de auto-ajustar el tamaño del DataGridview de acuerdo a las columnas? (para que no se vea lo color gris oscuro).

Comment: Si, en el DataGridview cambias la propiedad BackgroundColor para cambiar el  gris, y para que las columnas se ajusten prueba las opciones que tiene la propiedad AutoSizeColumnsMode

Comment: Te agradezco mucho!